# ASP.NET Core: BindRequired and appropriate error

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, model-binding

I have the following API method:

```
    [HttpPut]
    public async Task<IActionResult> SetToken([FromQuery, BindRequired]string token)
    {
```

so, as can we see, `token` is required.

Try to call method without `token`:

```
PUT api/profile/SetToken
```

and we get a response in the following json format:

{
    "token": [
        "A value for the 'token' property was not provided."
    ]
}

But I would like to get in another format, like this (it's unified format for the our project):

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": "string",
    "message": "string",
    "target": "string",
    "details": [
      {
        "code": "string",
        "message": "string",
        "target": "string"
      }
    ],
    "innererror": {
      "code": "string"
    }
  }
}
```

How to configure `BindRequired` such way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Afaik there is no Constructor, that takes a Error-message, so there’s no way to customize the Error. As mentioned in the [Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/model-binding?view=aspnetcore-2.2#customize-model-binding-behavior-with-attributes), that the Error is written to the ModelState.

What you can do, is write your own custom BindRequired-Attribute with a constructor, that accepts a Error-Message and writes it to the response.